# How to bind a TAO event channel onto a specific naming service

Tags: corba, tao

Assuming I've started a naming service with multicast turned off to listen on a specific ip:port configuration, how can I bind an event channel onto this naming service? I think this has to be possible because how can one determine on which name service to bind an event channel if there are multiple ones in a network?

It works fine with multicast turned on where the channel finds the naming service's location on its own. However I haven't found a way to make it known to the event service on startup.
Can this even be done directly from within code?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your question. Usually you use something in your ORB's environment to find the naming service of interest. For example, under omniORB there is a config file (or registry in Windows) that sets the initial reference for the naming service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -ORBInitRef commandline option which the ORB supports, for example use

```
client.exe -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc:iiop:localhost:12345/NameService
```

For more details see the [TAO documentation](https://svn.dre.vanderbilt.edu/viewvc/Middleware/trunk/TAO/docs/Options.html?view=co)